# Claims per policyholder follows a Poisson dist. but mean varies according to a Gamma distribution

Tags: statistics, finance, poisson-distribution, means, gamma-distribution

Can anyone help me on this?

The number of claims per policyholder in a portfolio follows a Poisson distribution with a mean number $Q$. Suppose that the mean number $Q$ varies over the policyholder population according to a Gamma distribution. Derive a formula for the probability of a randomly chosen policyholder making $r$ claims and why this may be more appropriate in many applications than the Poisson model?

Can anyone give any tip on how to do this and where can I find information that can help me?

Thanks

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability

Comment: Also [Poisson-Gamma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution#Gamma%E2%80%93Poisson_mixture).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Comment continued.** Following both my Comment and the one of @spaceisdarkgreen,
here is a simulation based on the specific case $Q \sim \mathsf{Gamma}(\text{shape}= \alpha = 3,\,
\text{rate} = \beta = 1/5).$ For an actuarial application, notice that the standard
deviation of this distribution is greater than the SD of a Poisson
distribution with mean 15. (For a general mathematical formula, you can adjust
the notation in Wikipedia to match the notation in your Question.)

```
set.seed(310)  # retain this statement to get exactly same simulation; otherwise omit
m = 10^6; r = numeric(m)
al = 3;  be = 1/5
for(i in 1:m) {
  q = rgamma(1, al, be)
  r[i] = rpois(1, q) }
mean(r);  sd(r)
## 14.98479
## 9.47612
```

[image]

Comment: I got it now. Thank you for your help.